# Does Mongoose implicitly convert the type of a field when comparing in the collection as per the defined schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a **mongoose schema** which has a following field:

```
var orderSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    status:{
          type: Types.String,
          enum: ['0','2', '6', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
          default: '0'
    }
});
Mongoose.model("order", orderSchema);
```

The above status field is of type **string**.

Assume you have a status field with the value `"2"` in the db.
If I run the below query from mongo shell, it will not give any result:

```
db.orders.findOne({status: 2});
```

will not work and as expected, this will work

```
db.orders.findOne({status: "2"});
```

However, when I executed the query using **mongoose(ver:"^4.13.14")** in my **node.js** code
This works:

```
orders.findOne({status: 2})
```

So, wanted to understand if mongoose does this conversion internally based on the defined schema?
Or something else is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum in mongoose is just a `string` with additional validator. You can observe the same behavior for regular strings like:

```
let orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status:{
      type: String
    }
  });

let Order = mongoose.model("orders", orderSchema);
let doc = await Order.findOne({ status: 2 });
```

Browsing the `find` [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) you can read that:

> The conditions are cast to their respective SchemaTypes before the command is sent.

Comment: Hey thanks for the link to the doc, was searching the same, could not find 